# CNTK RuntimeError: AddSequence: Sequences must be a least one frame long

Tags: python, cntk

I am getting error in following code:

```
x = cntk.input_variable(shape=c(8,3,1))
y = cntk.sequence.slice(x,1,0)
x0 = np.reshape(np.arange(48.0,dtype=np.float32),(2,8,1,3))
y.eval({x:x0})

Error : Sequences must be a least one frame long
```

But when I run this it runs fine :

```
x = cntk.input_variable(shape=c(3,2)) #change
y = cntk.sequence.slice(x,1,0)
x0 = np.reshape(np.arange(24.0,dtype=np.float32),(1,8,1,3))  #change
y.eval({x:x0})
```

I am not able to understand few things which `slice` method :

1. At what array level it's going to slice.
2. Acc. to documentation, second argument is `begin_index`, and next to it it `end_index`. How can `being_index` be greater than `end_index`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two versions of `slice()`, one for slicing tensors, and one for slicing sequences. Your example uses the one for sequences.

If your inputs are sequences (e.g. words), the first form, `cntk.slice()`, would individually slice every element of a sequence and create a sequence of the same length that consists of sliced tensors. The second form, `cntk.sequence.slice()`, will slice out a range of entries from the sequence. E.g. `cntk.sequence.slice(x, 13, 42)` will cut out sequence items 13..41 from `x`, and create a new sequence of length (42-13).

If you intended to experiment with the first form, please change to `cntk.slice()`. If you meant the sequence version, please try to enclose `x0` in an additional `[...]`. The canonical form of passing minibatch data is as a list of batch entries (e.g. MB size of 128 --> a list with 128 entries), where each batch entry is a tensor of shape `(Ti,) + input_shape` where `Ti` is the sequence length of the respective sequence. This

```
x0 = [ np.reshape(np.arange(48.0,dtype=np.float32),(2,8,1,3)) ]
```

would denote a minibatch with a single entry (1 list entry), where the entry is a sequence of 2 sequence items, where each sequence item has shape (8,1,3).

The begin and end indices can be negative, in order to index from the end (similar to Python slices). Unlike Python however, 0 is a valid end index that refers to the end.